# Remove the duplicate from list of dict in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have dict like this

```
d=[{'a':1,'b':2},{'a':2,'b':2},{'a':3},{'a':1}]
```

So i need  like

```
d=[{'a':1,'b':2},{'a':2,'b':2},{'a':3}]
```

Remove duplicate

Comment: It's my first question so by mistake sorry

Comment: No it's list of dict

Comment: Can you please help

Comment: Can you please give me a answer

Comment: What do you mean by *"duplicate"* ?

Comment: value of a  is same

Comment: I have same value of a in different dict but i want remove the a value from list

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Comment: Why is `'a': 1` removed and not `'b': 2`? It also appears two times

Answer (score 0):

1. Learn more about Python data types and theirs functions. Here is one tutorial for [dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)
2. As what I know using list of dictionaries is a bad practice
3. Here is my solution it could be not so elegant, but it is working. Also remove duplicates means remove ALL of them, so I remove all list elements where they were repeated.

   ```
   d = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 2, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3}, {'a': 1}]
   temp = []

   for i in d:
       for x, y in i.items():
       temp_var = [x, y]
       if temp_var in temp:
           d.pop(d.index(i))
       else:
           temp.append(temp_var)

   print(d)

   # result [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3}]
   ```
4. P.S.: Keep learning and have a nice day :)